# Cannot find proper JSON array syntax for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, highcharts

Hope all is well. I am running into a little trouble with setting up a JSON array via PHP and pushing it into Highcharts.

At the moment I generate the array like this:

```
    $stack[] = array($commname => $countit);
    $stack = json_encode($stack);
```

When I print_r the array I get the following:

> [{"Crude Oil":69},{"Natural Gas":554},{"Liquid Natural
>   Gas":152},{"Power":40},{"Coal":10},{"Weather":21},{"Macroeconomics":67},{"Miscellaneous":45},{"Prices":50},{"Freight":14},{"Forecasts":16}]

I then pass the array to javascript like this:

```
var stack = <?php echo json_encode( $stack ) ?>;
```

.. and then pass it into the following highcharts array like this:

```
var text = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ]
            }]
        };
text.series[0].data.push(stack);
```

... But this does not work. I think my array 'stack' is not prepared properly, because highcharts wants it to be in this format: [["Crude oil", 35],["Natural Gas", 45] etc...]

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

G.

Comment: Convert your JSON to an array in the js part.

Comment: What error do you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways
- form json to this form:

```
{name:"Crude Oil", y:69}
```

- get JSON then use loop and push to new series data array and then refer to it in the highcharts option.

Comment: This is the correct answer -only when I output the array as follows did it work for me: `$stack[] = array('name' => $commname, 'y' => $countit);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery.parseJSON

> jQuery.parseJSON()

```
var stack = <?php echo json_encode( $stack ) ?>;
stack  = jQuery.parseJSON(stack);
```

Comment: Arun, I have found that when I loop through my array like so then it generates the graph properly (see code below). Can I not do the same thing with just a simple line? `var i;
for (i = 0; i < stack.length; ++i) {
text.series[0].data.push(stack[i]);`
}

Answer (score 0):

You should generate source array like this:

`$stack[] = array($commname, $countit);`

or like this

`$stack[] = array('name' => $commname, 'y' => $countit);`